# YouTube on Chrome on MacBook Air uses excess CPU

Tags: google-chrome, cpu, youtube

I have a problem with YouTube on Chrome on my MacBook Air. If I start YouTube the CPU goes to about 100% immediately. If I kill the YouTube (YT) tab **the CPU stays at 100%** for about 15 - 16 minutes then drops off to almost nothing. Activity Monitor shows me that it is the main Google Chrome process itself (not helper or renderer) using all the CPU and it has the Google icon next to it. I am running Mojave 10.14.3. This is a relatively new problem for me. I do not have this issue when I run YT on Safari.

Answer (score 1):

Use the YouTube App instead to watch your video; it uses less CPU.

To open YouTube videos from  Chrome, right click the in the address bar, select open this link then choose an app icon.